# Redirect log4j2 logs into java.util.logging

Tags: java, tomcat, log4j, log4j2, java.util.logging

I want to use Log4J2 API, but I want all logs to be processed by `java.util.logging` (which will use Tomcat implementation). For example it's possible with SLF4J and slf4j-jdk14 library. Is it possible with Log4J2? I've found log4j-jul library, but it seems to work the other way: JUL API will be redirected to Log4J implementation.

I'm aware that it's possible to replace Tomcat logging subsystem with Log4J2, but it seems a fragile solution to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you consider using Log4j 2 to handle the logging as fragile? Have you seen http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-appserver/index.html?

No, Log4j does not provide a bridge to route logging to java.util.logging. You can route the Log4j 2 API to SLF4J and then route that to java.util.logging.

Comment: Because Tomcat already have logging implementation and I don't see why should I replace it, as I'm choosing which logging API to use in my application. I used log4j in the past, but it seems that slf4j is more flexible.

Comment: You used Log4j or Log4j 2?  The Log4j 2 API is a superset of the SLF4J API so it is hard to understand how SLF4J could be more flexible. See https://www.ralphgoers.com/post/getting-the-most-out-of-the-log4j-2-api for a description of some of the significant features available in the Log4j 2 API that are not in SLF4J. Also, when you are speaking of tomcat vs Log4j 2 you are talking about the Log4j implementation, not its API. Those are two different topics. When you pick tomcat logging you are essentially using java.util.logging, which is extremely limited in what it can do.